# How can I start the first story mission?

Tags: assassins-creed-rebellion

I have completed the first few tutorial missions and now when I login, the app prompts me to take the first Story Mission, and will not let me tap elsewhere.

[image: First story mission]

However, when I tap on this mission to start it I end up on the mission screen unable to launch the mission presumably as I lack the required 3 envelopes.

[image: First mission starting]

How can I proceed in the game at this point? I don't know how to acquire more envelopes.

[Here is a thread on the Ubisoft forums with users experiencing the same issue](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1895078-Assassin-s-Creed-Rebellion-Stuck-in-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue now, but it's not ideal.

TL;DR Start again from the beginning. Logout, if you sync'd with Facebook.

You will need to logout of the game if you sync'd with Facebook. Tap the top left corner to get to your profile, and hit logout.

Then start the game again from the beginning.

Now when you build the Intel Room your whole intel will fill automatically. This gave me 105 intel envelopes.

Then I could progress with the game.

Worth noting that if you do this approach, your old save game will still be on Facebook. So if you lose your phones local data, you will lose progress. I haven't found a way to overwrite the Facebook save with a new one.

When you delete the app directly from Facebook, it does not wipe your save.